# Power BI How to use the Total (like the one in a matrix) in a measure

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

My question is: How do I use the total, like the one at the bottom of a Matrix in a measure. So that I can use it to find a percentage ie. Sales rate. I have tried running totals, all selected and filtered functions to no avail. Ideally I would like to hold this total value in a variable and then use it to divide.

For example, (see images below)
I would take the state of AK and the value of 8 to divide by the total (143)
so that AK = 5.59%  (8/143)*100

And end up with something like
State   Sold        Rate
AK      8           5.59%
AL      78          54.54%
AR      57          39.86%

Question 2A

[image: Question 2A]

Question 2B

[image: Question 2B]

I have tried using the measures below:

```
Monthly Running Total = IF(
[x_sales_sold] <> BLANK(),
CALCULATE(
    [x_sales_sold],
    FILTER(
        ALL('power_cal'[the_date]),
        'power_cal'[the_date] <= MAX('power_cal'[the_date])
    )
))

Allselected_total = CALCULATE(
[x_sales_sold]
,ALLSELECTED('lookup_census'[state_abbrev]))


x_sales_sold = CALCULATE(
SUM(fae_dt[is_sold])
,FILTER(fae_dt,fae_dt[is_sold] == 1))

x_percent = VAR vRT  =  
    CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS(fae_dt)
            ,FILTER(fae_dt,fae_dt[is_sold]==1)
            )RETURN (DIVIDE([x_sales_sold],vRT))
```

To summarize, How do i hold a total in a variable for use in a calculation in the measure?
If someone could at least point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you whomever is reading this for your time.

Comment: Your Allselected_total should do the job, because you remove filter context from state column; If this didnt work, then check if you have "sort by" set to default; OR Provide sample data on which your problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Got it. Will rework this and give that a shot. Thank you.